# Nice functional inequality

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Hello during a problem I come across an another problem :

> Let $x>0$ and $f(x)$ a continuous  stricly increasing function such as $f(x)-x\geq m$ with $m$ a real number and $$x+\frac{1}{x}\leq f(x)+\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$

Prove that we have :
$$f(x)f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\geq 1   \quad         \forall x>0$$

The original problem was the following :

$$\cosh(x)\leq e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}\quad \forall x>0$$

If we put $y=e^x$ this has the form of the beginning with :

$$f(x)=x^{\ln(x)0.5}$$

Many thanks for your contributions.

Comment: Your "original problem" is answered here: [Proving $\ln \cosh x\leq \frac{x^2}{2}$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1149780/proving-ln-cosh-x-leq-fracx22-for-x-in-mathbbr)

Comment: Yes thanks you very much .Have you nice idea to prove the general inequality Martin R ?

Comment: If $f(x) \ge x$ is given for all $x > 0$, then $f(x)f(\frac{1}{x}) \ge x \frac 1x = 1$ is trivial.

Comment: Thanks and now what do you think about ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right, there exists a counterexample. Put $\Bbb R_+=\{x\in\Bbb R: x>0\}$ and define a function $f:\Bbb R_+\to\Bbb R_+$ by putting

$$f(x)= \cases{x/2,\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;   \mbox{if $x\le 1/2$},\\ 
(7x-3)/2, \mbox{if $1/2\le x\le 1$ },\\ 
x+1\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\,, \mbox{ if $x\ge 1$.}}$$

Then the function $f$ is continuous and strictly increasing, $f(x)-x\ge -1/4$ and  $x+\frac{1}{x}\leq f(x)+f(\frac{1}{x})$ for each $x$, but $f(2)f(1/2)=3/4<1$.

Comment: Yes it works (+1) but I would like to discuss with you what's happend if we exclude the angular point ? And what's happend if the function is differentiable  everywhere ? Thanks for your interest .

Comment: @FatsWallers I think these details are not essential and can be easily obtained. The problem arises because $f(x)>0$ can be very small for $x<1$ while assuring all other conditions by sufficiently large $f(x)$ for $x\ge 1$. For instance, if $f(x)\ge 0$ for each $x$ and $f(x)\ge x+1$ for each $x\ge 1$ then already $f(x)+f(1/x)\ge x+1/x$ and $f(x)-x\ge -1$ for each $x$.

Comment: Yes you are right ! A last question :) Can you prove there exists an interval where $f(x)f(\frac{1}{x})\geq 1$.I think it's very difficult ^^.Thanks for your sagacity .

Comment: @FatsWallers You are right again, because this is impossible. Put $f(x)= x-1/x+1$, if $x\ge 1$ and $f(x)=2x-1$, if $x\le 1$. Then $x+\frac{1}{x}=f(x)+f(\frac{1}{x})$, but for $x\ge 1$ we have $f(x)f(1/x)\ge 1$ iff $(1-x)(x^2+x-2)\ge 0$, that is iff $x=1$.

Comment: Good, I have an other problem wich is difficult .Have you some idea on this ? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2512249/inequality-with-power-and-logarithm .Have a good day.

Comment: @FatsWallers Done. PS. It was not difficult.